# In Lucas Sequence, should numerator always be even when calculating $v_{2k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

In the [Lucas Probable prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Implementing_a_Lucas_probable_prime_test) one of the steps is to use the formula

$V_{2k}=v_k^2-2Q^k=(v^2_k+DU_k^2)/2$

I have found sometimes the numerator $V^2_k+DU_k^2$ is odd. I was wondering if that makes I've made an earlier mistake or if this is to be expected? There are other related formulas, $U_{2k+1}=({PU_{2k}+V_{2k}})/2$ and $V_{2k+1}=({DU_{2k}+PV_{2k}})/2$ where the article contains specific instructions on what to do if the numerator is odd. This makes me think that $v^2_k+DU_k^2$ shouldn't be odd. Also someone pointed out that it definitely should be an integer because $(v^2_k+DU_k^2)=V_k^2-2Q^k$.

If it is in fact correct that the numerator can be odd, what is the correct thing to do when dividing by 2? I've seen

1. divide by 2 and use the floor function i.e. always round down ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735100/lucas-sequence-and-primality-tests-is-this-test-deterministic))
2. if odd, add on n because all calculations are done module n (described in linked wiki article)
3. multiply numerator by n+1 regardless if odd or even

Are all these techniques equivalent?

An example of when this happens is $n=7$ and $D=5$ then $v_4=7$ which is congruent to 0 then $v_8=\frac{0+5 \cdot 3^2}{2}=\frac{45}{2}$. I think it normally happens to last v term for prime numbers.

In general when dealing in modular arithmetic, is it assumed everything is an integer?

Comment: only cases I can think of that can cause odd values, is odd $v_k$ and one or more of the others even, or both $D$ and $u_k$ odd with $v_k$ even.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee example added

Comment: This reduces to -2 in mod 7.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee what reduces to -2 in mod 7? Are you saying that's what you got when you compute $v_8$? How can you get a negative number?

Comment: $-2\equiv (7-2)\equiv 5\bmod 7$ it's another name for 5 as they are congruent. via $45\equiv 3\equiv -4\bmod 7$. dividing by 2 gives -2.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Using modular arithmetic you can make the numerator even in that sense. But that is my question, shouldn't it already be even? If you feel the question is well written could you up vote it so it gets more attention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97960/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-northerner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working modulo an odd $n$, it's not meaningful to say that a value is "even" or "odd", since an even number can be converted to an odd number modulo $n$. You also don't need to: you can always divide by $2$.

Of the solutions you suggest, the first one definitely doesn't work: when dividing an odd number by $2$, we shouldn't take the floor. An easy way to see that this is wrong is that it's not consistent when we take a different numerator in the same equivalence class modulo $n$. For example, $3 \equiv 10\pmod{7}$, but if we divide by $2$ and round down, we get $1$ and $5$, and $1 \not\equiv 5 \pmod{7}$.

It's definitely valid to divide an odd $k$ by $2$ by taking $\frac{k+n}{2}$; since $k \equiv k+n \pmod{n}$, this is just taking a different representation of the same number. This explains your second method.

For the third method: Since $2 \cdot \frac{n+1}{2} \equiv n+1 \equiv 1 \pmod n$, $\frac{n+1}{2}$ (an integer!) is the multiplicative inverse of $2$ modulo $n$. So we can always multiply by $\frac{n+1}{2}$ instead of dividing by $2$. I'm not sure this is as efficient as adding $n$ to the numerator, but it is a possibility.

Finally, for the specific application you've got, another approach is to replace the recurrence relations
$$
   \begin{cases}
     U_{2k} = U_k V_k \\
     V_{2k} = \frac12(V_k^2 + D U_k^2)
   \end{cases}
   \qquad
   \begin{cases}
     U_{2k+1} = \frac12(P U_{2k} + V_{2k}) \\
     V_{2k+1} = \frac12(D U_{2k} + PV_{2k})
   \end{cases}
$$
by the modified recurrence relations

$$
   \begin{cases}
     U_{2k}' = 2 U_k' V_k' \\
     V_{2k}' = V_k'^2 + D U_k'^2
   \end{cases}
   \qquad
   \begin{cases}
     U_{2k+1}' = P U_{2k}' + V_{2k}' \\
     V_{2k+1}' = D U_{2k}' + PV_{2k}'
   \end{cases}
$$
We get these recurrence relations by the substitution $(U_k', V_k') = (2^{k-1}U_k, 2^{k-1}V_k)$, which gets rid of the extra $\frac12$'s floating around.

In the end, you'll get $U_{\delta(n)}' = 2^{\delta(n)-1} U_{\delta(n)}$. Since $n$ is odd, we have $U_{\delta(n)}' \equiv 0 \pmod n$ if and only if $U_{\delta(n)} \equiv 0 \pmod n$, so we haven't changed anything - but the new recurrence relations don't require us to divide by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it is even before you mod it $7+5\cdot 3^2= 52=7(7)+3$.  As the later is really what modular arithmetic talks with, it's not surprising **at all** to get an odd resulting numerator. You can then rewrite it as $7(8)-4=52$ , and then dividing by 2, we get: $$7(4)-2=26$$ Which then gives use a remainder in mod of $-2\equiv(7-2)\equiv 5\pmod 7$